# apache camel parse large file splitting data in batches

Tags: java, split, apache-camel, aggregate

I have a large file that I want to import in a databse table.
Every line in the file represents a row in the DB.
My requirements are to split the file lines into batches and save every batch on the DB (within a transaction). If a transaction fails I want to terminate the import avoiding to import subsequent batches.

Starting from [this tutorial](http://www.catify.com/2012/07/09/parsing-large-files-with-apache-camel/) I have build this route:

```
        from("file:/path")
            .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
                .streaming()
                .bean(ParseLine.class)
                .setHeader("foo", constant("foo"))
                .aggregate(header("foo"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
                .completionSize(100)
                .completionTimeout(1000)
                .bean(SaveBatch.class)
            .end();
```

where the `ParseLine` beans returns an object ready for a database insert, the `SaveBatch` bean is the piece of code that do the inserts
and the `ArrayListAggregationStrategy` is:

```
class ArrayListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        ArrayList<Object> list = null;
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(newBody);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ArrayList.class);
            list.add(newBody);
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this route doesn't stop file processing if an exception is thrown by SaveBatch bean, but the bean will continue to receive all the subsequent aggregates.
Is there a strategy to the splitter on the first exception thrown by SaveBean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.stopOnException()` to your splitter as shown here [Splitter (stopOnException)](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-Stopprocessingincaseofexception) e.g.

```
    from("file:/path")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).stopOnException()
            .streaming()
            .bean(ParseLine.class)
            .setHeader("foo", constant("foo"))
            .aggregate(header("foo"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
            .completionSize(100)
            .completionTimeout(1000)
            .bean(SaveBatch.class)
        .end();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify two things on the split itself add a parameter stopOnException=true
and then you can specify the onexception for the route or the particular part of the route and mark handled as true. Once the exception occurs the route will stop split and also when the exception is thrown your overall route exception policy will handle it as necessary.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">>
<camel:onException>
        <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
        <camel:handled>
            <camel:constant>true</camel:constant>
        </camel:handled>
        <camel:to uri="log:sundarstop?showAll=true&amp;multiline=true" />
        <camel:stop></camel:stop>
    </camel:onException>
<camel:route>
  <camel:from uri="file://///"/>
  <camel:to .../>
</camel:route>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an exception handler in camel and start throwing the appropriate exceptions from `ArrayListAggregationStrategy` class.

Comment: thanks for you reply. How can i throw an Exception from ArrayListAggregationStrategy? I tryed to manage exceptions inside the AggregationStrategy without success. Can you give more details?

Comment: Some useful links: http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html and http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-retrieve-the-thrown-exception-during-processing-an-exchange.html. Let me know in case you need any further help.